# Classic ASP: recursive function to build a tree from an array

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, tree

I extracted all my records from database with .GetRows(), so I have now a big array

```
arrTree = rsTree.GetRows()
```

To make sure it works, I can print with this:

```
dim x
response.write "<table>"
For x = 0 to ubound(arrTree, 2)
   response.write "<tr>"
   response.write("<td>" + trim(x+1))
   response.write("<td>" + trim(arrTree(0,x))) 'ID
   response.write("<td>" + trim(arrTree(1,x))) 'PARENT
   response.write("<td>" + trim(arrTree(2,x))) 'NAME
next
response.write "</table>"
```

That's fine, now I'd like a recursive function to build an HTML tree/menu: and here is where I have all my troubles

I tried to "port" a working PHP function to ASP, but it doesn't work and get caught in a loop

```
Function Tree(varAncestor, varArray)
    ' varAncestor is the parent from where to start
    Dim x
    varHasChildren = false
    For x = 0 to ubound(varArray, 2)
        If CInt(varArray(1,x)) = varAncestor Then
            If (varHasChildren = false AND varAncestor <> 0) Then 
                varHasChildren = true
                Response.Write("<ul>")
            End If
        %>
        <li><% Response.Write(varArray(2,x)) %>
        <% Call Tree(varArray(1,x), varArray) %>
        </li>
        <%
        End If
    Next
    If (varHasChildren = true AND varAncestor <> 0) Then 
        Response.Write("</ul>")
    End If
End Function

Response.Write("<ul>")
Call Tree(0, arrTree)
Response.Write("</ul>")
```

There's something wrong with this but I can't understand where... Please, can you help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, did it at last! Here's the basic version

```
Function Tree(varAncestor, varArray)
    varHasChildren = false
    For x = 0 to ubound(varArray, 2)
        If (CInt(varArray(1, x)) = varAncestor) Then
            If (varHasChildren = false AND varAncestor > 0) Then 
                varHasChildren = true
                Response.Write("<ul>")
            End If
        %>
        <li><% Response.Write(varArray(2, x)) %>
            <% Call Tree(varArray(0, x), varArray) %>
        </li>
        <%
        End If
    Next
    If (varHasChildren = true AND varAncestor > 0) Then 
        Response.Write("</ul>")
    End If
End Function
```

And here's the improved version I use:

```
Function Tree(varAncestor, varArray)
    varHasChildren = false
    For x = 0 to ubound(varArray, 2)
        If (CInt(varArray(1, x)) = varAncestor) Then
            If (varHasChildren = false AND varAncestor > 0) Then 
                varHasChildren = true
                Response.Write("<ul>")
            End If
        %>
        <li class="<% If (Request.QueryString("iCat") = CStr(varArray(0, x))) Then Response.Write("active") %>">
            <a href="cat.asp?iCat=<% Response.Write(varArray(0, x)) %>">
                <span class="fa fa-fw fa-folder-o text-warning"></span> 
                <% Response.Write(varArray(2, x)) %>
            </a>
            <% Call Tree(varArray(0, x), varArray) %>
        </li>
        <%
        End If
    Next
    If (varHasChildren = true AND varAncestor > 0) Then 
        Response.Write("</ul>")
    End If
End Function
```